# Densities of strong solutions to SDE's

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following problem for which I could not find appropriate references:
Suppose we have $V\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\mathrm{Hess}(V)>0$ (or a bit more restrictive, I could assume $\mathrm{Hess}(V)\geq R$ for some $R>0$).
Then consider the following SDE ($(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ being an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion):
$$dX_t = \sqrt{2}dB_t - \nabla V(X_t) dt$$
I would like to know the following:

Does at any time $t > 0$ the distribution of a strong solution to this SDE have a density (wrt. to the Lebesgue measure)?

I know that at least in the Gaussian case the answer to the question is positive, since in this case the SDE is solved by the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, which is normally distributed, and strong uniqueness holds for the SDE so any two solutions have the same distribution.
I am not sure about the general case though when $V$ differs from the Gaussian potential.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "general case"? What is $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ (in the general case)?

Comment: Sorry, with the general case I mean when $V$ is not the Gaussian potential but the general function defined in the beginning (i.e. $V\in C^2$ etc.).

Comment: $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ should be a Brownian Motion in any case.

Comment: If $V$ is smooth, Hormander's theorem guarantees smooth transition densities: see section 7 of [this nice set of notes](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Convergence.pdf). However, I think that a shorter and more elementary use of Girsanov and Novikov can do the trick here as well, but the details may get a bit annoying, see [this question and perhaps try to adapt the tricks used there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133691/can-i-apply-the-girsanov-theorem-to-an-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process).

Comment: thank you shalop for the nice reference. so it definitely works at least when $V\in C^\infty$, which is very good to know.